# Styling anchor element

Tags: html, css

I have nav menu with few anchors. For example "HOME" "ABOUT" and "CONTACT"

I have the next question.

If I am on "HOME" page, I want to style "HOME" anchor on this page differently, and the same for other pages and their anchors respectively.

One of my ideas was to style each page separately, using :nth element?

But maybe someone knows another way to do that.

PS:     Sorry, I was not clear, I don't want to change the color, I need to add the underline. So it is not duplicated question

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to add an `active` class to the current page. This way you will be able to add some style on your home nav if you are on the home page.
I don't know your stack, but could be done by your server side, or by javascript.